# Is there a way to perform a student t-test using postgresql

Tags: java, sql, database, postgresql, statistics

I have a bunch of data in a database.

```
'Year', 'Disabled', 'non-disabled'
 1990,     5,             3
 1991,     2,             1
```

I want to be able to find the average of all the years for each column. So I want the average of the numbers for disabled and then I want the average of the years for non disabled. I then want to compare the two values using a t-test to see if there's a significant difference between the two.

Can I do that? Does postgresql have a way for me to enter in two values  and get a p-value using a t test?

Comment: Have you tried to use sql aggregates like `avg(some_value)`?

Comment: PostgreSQL its self has only limited stats functions built in, but the PL/R extension supports more statistical tests and other features than you could ever want. That said, I'd probably get the mean with `avg` and the standard deviation with `stddev` , then plug the values into the t-test on the Java side.

Answer (score 3):

While an old question, I had to do the same thing and couldn't find a direct answer so I created my own query to do it. If there are any statistical interpretation errors, please help me improve it.

```
WITH table_column1_stats_CTE AS (
    SELECT avg(column1) AS _mean, 
           stddev(column1) AS _stddev, 
           stddev(column1)/sqrt(count(*)) AS _se, 
           count(*) - 1 AS _df 
    FROM table
), table_column2_stats_CTE AS (
    SELECT avg(column2) AS _mean 
    FROM table
), t_value_CTE AS (
    SELECT _df, 
           abs(a._mean - b._mean) / (_stddev/sqrt(_df+1)) AS t_value 
    FROM table_column1_stats_CTE a, table_column2_stats_CTE b
), all_results_CTE AS (
    SELECT *, 
           row_number() OVER (ORDER BY abs(a.df - _df) ASC) AS rank 
    FROM t_test_table a, t_value_CTE b
)
SELECT 
        CASE WHEN t_value <= p01 THEN 0.99 
             WHEN t_value <= p05 THEN 0.95 
             WHEN t_value <= p1 THEN 0.9 
             WHEN t_value <= p2 THEN 0.8 ELSE 0.0 
        END AS significance
FROM all_results_CTE 
WHERE rank = 1
```

If I could attach the t_test_table I would, but you can just create it by duplicating:
https://jimgrange.wordpress.com/2015/12/05/statistics-tables-where-do-the-numbers-come-from/

Comment: Why did you not use pl/Python or pl/R to do this? I did not read through your query, but it is fairly complex and hard to debug

Comment: the asker wanted a PostGRES method, so I made a PostGRES method.